# Split Angular Module into smaller chunks using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to split a giant angular with a LOT of components into chunks, I know this giant module shouldn't exists but at this point of the project I can't touch the code a lot.

Does anyone know how to make webpack split the build into smaller files?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting code into asynchronously loaded chunks is one thing, another is to load them and use. You'll need to change existing code (you may start with smaller/easier components)

Currently there are two ways to achieve it in Angular:

1. Lazily loaded feature modules

See: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules

2. Loading components using `dynamic import`

See example:

```js
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) container: ViewContainerRef

async ngOnInit() {
  const { SomeComponent } = await import('./some.component')
  this.footerRef.createComponent(SomeComponent)
}
```

Template:

```html
<ng-container #container></ng-container>
```

Comment: Lazy loading didn't work for me. I'm using standalone components (angular 17). Specifically I included `@angular/fire` but lazy loading the components that are using Firebase didn't reduce the initial bundle size.